# How to detect browser close event in node js?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have used Electron(formerly Atom Shell) to create desktop app using NodeJS.

I am using following code to open an url into browser

`var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
spawn('open', ['http://www.stackoverflow.com']);`

Please note that I am not using `Electron BrowserWindow`, this is a regular browser window.

I want to perform an action when user closes this browser window. How do I detect close event of this spawned browser?

Comment: Why not just use Electron's BrowserWindow and lock it down, i.e. turn off node integrations?

Comment: I have created a library which is to be used by Electron and a Visual studio extension. This library is going to open this browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing the [event emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  browser = spawn('open', ['http://www.stackoverflow.com']);

browser.on('close', function() {
  // Handle event
});
```

Comment: yes, tried this. This 'close' event fires as soon as the command is executed, even before the browser is about to open. Doesn't fire when browser is closed.

Comment: Then 'open' is propably a startupscript of some kind (bat, sh, etc). Have you tried replacing 'open' with the path to the executable?

Comment: just tried, if I use executable path (google chrome path) directly, it throws error with code EACCES.

Comment: That's a bit tricky since Chrome keeps changing pid and adds a pid for each session, cache block, db store etc. You'd have to locate the main browser window-pid (os specific) and poll it for events